# Need htaccess rule to differentiate directories and query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've an url like below mentioned.

```
abc.com/test/abc/hello/?hello=world&foo=bar
```

I've to differentiate directories and query string separate using htaccess

I need to have result like:

```
Array
(
    [data] => test/abc/hello/
    [hello] => world
    [foo] => bar
)
```

I've tried many htaccess methods but won't got the result what I want. I've tried below methods

If I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\-\/]+)$ index.php?data=$1
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => test/abc/hello/
)
```

And when tried:

```
RewriteRule .* test.php [L]
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [hello] => world
    [foo] => bar
)
```

But suggest me htaccess rule from which I can get result like

```
Array
(
    [data] => test/abc/hello/
    [hello] => world
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Can anybody help me to get my results from htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work (Not TESTED):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w\-\/]+)$ index.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Flag QSA: QueryString Appended.

But I'm rather reserved as you use this to get data, hello and foo, it's too costful. In PHP you can use this:

```
<?php
$data = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$hello = $_GET["hello"];
$foo = $_GET["foo"];
?>
```

Without any Rewriting required.